# Vuejs component doesn't update when changing variable

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm learning Vue.js and have been able to write a simple list/detail application. Selecting the first item renders the detail component with the correct data, however when I select a different item the detail component doesn't reload with the right information.

For example:

```
<template>
<div>
    <detail :obj="currentObject"></detail>
</div>
</template>
<script>
export default: {
  data: function(){
    return {
      currentObject: null,
      objs = [
        {name:'obj 1'},
        {name:'obj 2'}
      ]
   };
  }
}
</script>
```

When I do `this.currentObject = objs[0]` the component `detail` updates with the correct content. However the next time I call `this.currentObject = objs[1]`, the component `detail` no longer updates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure what's the context your are switching the data on your `currentObject`, but the below is a concept detail component and when you switch the `objs` it updated the prop `:obj` and seems working fine.

Looking at your code, you should declare `objs` using `:` not `=`.

```
data: function() {
    return {
      currentObject: null,
      objs: [
        {name:'obj 1'},
        {name:'obj 2'}
      ]
   };
 }
```

Here is the concept detail component, run the snippet to check it working.

```js
Vue.component('detail', {
  props: ['obj'],
  template: '<div>{{ obj }}</div>'
})

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      bToggle: false,
      currentObject: null,
      objs: [
        {name:'obj 1'},
        {name:'obj 2'}
      ]
    }
   },
   created(){
    this.switchData();
   },
   methods: {
    switchData() {
      if(!this.bToggle){
        this.currentObject = this.objs[0];
      }else{
        this.currentObject = this.objs[1];
      }
      this.bToggle = !this.bToggle;
   }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <button @click="switchData()"> switch </button>
    <detail :obj="currentObject"></detail>
</div>
```

Comment: This, although not the complete solution, pointed me in the right direction. Pretty much like @cal_br_mar mentioned, what I missed was a `watch` on the property `obj` so that when it changes some logic - that wasn't in the example - also runs.